# Grails assign id to generator identity

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have domain objects which have all:

```
id generator: 'identity'
```

I can't change that, because items are inserted from all over the application and it relies on that. Now I have a task, where i need to import rows, but these rows already have ids.

So, what are my option here, how can I insert them with assigned id? I have tried save and hibernate replicate methods, but all i get is an error that id is null.

Comment: Use the database migration plugin to migrate the data via SQL insert statements or use Groovy SQL to issue insert statements. Those are your options.

Answer (score 0):

Grails, actually Hibernate leaves it to the database to assign the id. You may be able to insert the rows with SQL. For example, [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) will allow you but you may need to reset the autoincrement so that it has unused IDs ahead.